# Does simple 'crypto' in code fall under iOS Export Compliance?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store

I programmed an App that performs some simple encryption. A user enters a text and a codeword and the app shows back an 'encrypted' text. My 'encryption' just shifts some characters (e.g. 'a' becomes a '5' depending on the codeword). Reading the export compliance in the App Store, made me unsure about whether my app is now using encryption or not? I thought they just mean encryption like RSA or SSL or things like that or does the encryption function in my app also fall under that?